# Dual boot in macbook air

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, mac, macbook

I am running a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018). I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I am getting ACPI error when I am booting up. I will upload a picture of the error so that all can understand my problem.

please help if you can find out the problem.

thankyou.

[error picture :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrMLk.jpg)

Comment: Why are you trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?   It reaches the end of it's *standard support* next month (5 years from release in 2016-April; ie. 16.04) so is this a short-term project.  Why not use a release that has years left of support (instead of weeks)

Comment: ya, I tried with the latest version. The same type of error comes...@guiverc

Comment: You are providing no specifics, eg. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with 5 available stack choices at installation time (post install you have only 2 as they 16.10, 17.04 & 17.10 stacks will auto-upgrade to 18.04 post or during install) given LTS releases have two stack options (one which changes during life-time). The *latest* means nothing to me here as it's vague (do you mean *groovy* or 20.10, a *daily* or something else?)  Please be specific  (eg. media used for 16.04 was 16.04 or 16.04.1 (ie. GA stack) ? 16.04.2?(16.10 stack), 16.04.3? (17.04 stack) ... 16.04.7?

Comment: If your box was fully-patched you may only be able to install 16.04.7 anyway but you gave no specifics, and *latest* is vague?  Common sense says *groovy* or 20.10 but most users here don't mean that, so its safest to ignore terms like *latest* from end-users. Please be specific when you provide details (and they should be added to your question).